# UIGestureRecognizer is only added for subView but it is also working on parentView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

Here is my code :

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognizer:)];
    [self.colorView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.colorView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.colorView];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];
    startingPoint=touchPoint;
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.colorView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);



}
```

so it have to only work on the colorView but what happens is [image],that touch is working on self.view inside also ,how to solve this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add:

```
 self.colorView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

It will resolve your issue.

> A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the
>   bounds of the view.
>
> Declaration OBJECTIVE-C @property(nonatomic) BOOL clipsToBounds
>   Discussion Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to
>   the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend
>   beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default
>   value is NO.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>   Link: [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds)

So because it's NO. So interaction will extent to super view. When you set to YES. It only work on your subview.

Comment: did you mean `self.colorView.layer.clipsToBounds = YES;`?

Comment: @vien vu its working but i like to know how its happening

Comment: @vienvu thanks,now i understood the concept of clipsToBounds

Comment: @vienvu do you know how to remove that line from view if user touches the reset button ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar It's another question. But you can try this way. create array save your layer `[self.layerArray addObject:shapeLayer];` and when reset: `
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    
    for (CAShapeLayer *layer in self.layerArray) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
    
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Views track touches that started inside of them even when the touch goes outside their bounds (that's why you can hold a button, drag out and it'll still be selected while you are within a certain distance)

You can use `CGRectContainsPoint` to only add a point if it's inside the view.

Comment: how to add that CGRectContainPoint brother @EmilioPelaez.